# Find the configuration of variables that gives max value for a function

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Let `N` be a real number > 0.

Given a function in `k` real, distinct variables, where **the sum of the variables has to equal N**, how would I go about finding the configuration of the k variables for which the function has the maximum possible value?

*Example:*

$N = 100;$

$ Z =  3a + 5b + sin(c) - d(e^2) $

How would I find the values of $a,b,c,d,e$ for which $Z$ is max, where $a+b+c+d+e = N$ ?

I am looking for something that will work for any n number of variables, and N of any size.

Comment: For $Z$ no max. Try $a=b=c=0, d=-M, e=M+N, M\to +\infty$

Comment: The function I wrote is just an example. How would I go about solving this problem for an arbitrary function $ f $?
As in, what algorithm/steps should I use to solve this.

Comment: It is a constrained optimization problem, which is solved by method of substitution, by Lagrange mulipliers method, graphically, etc

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the notation, let $x=(a, b, c, d, e) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g(x)=a+b+c+d+e -N$. Then you can use [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) which in this case means, that $\nabla Z = \lambda \nabla g$ at the maximum. Geometrically, the constraint $g=0$ defines a $n - 1$ dimensional manifold (in your case just a plane with the parametrization $e= a+b+c+d - N$) and the gradient has to be perpendicular to that manifold.

The alternative is, you use the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) (or another method) to solve the constraint equation and then you get a coordinate chart $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^n \to S = \{ y\in \mathbb{R}^n : g(y)=0\}$ which you can use to analyze the function $Z\circ \phi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by standard calculus methods.